Lambda Calculus - Lambda Term Categories
I am new to $\lambda$-calculus and I am curious about the $\lambda$-term: $(\lambda x \cdot v)(\lambda v \cdot x)$
From the following definition (Harrison, 1997):
Lambda calculus is based on a formal notion of lambda term, and these terms are built up from variables and some fixed set of constants using the operations of function application and lambda abstraction. This means that every lambda term falls into one of the following four categories:

Variables: these are indexed by arbitrary alphanumeric strings; typically we will use single letters from towards the end of the alphabet, e.g. x, y and z.
Constants: how many constants there are in a given syntax of lambda terms depends on context. Sometimes there are none at all. We will also denote them by alphanumeric strings, leaving context to determine when they are meant to be constants.
Combinations, i.e. the application of a function s to an argument t; both these components s and t may themselves be arbitrary λ-terms. We will write combinations simply as s t. We often refer to s as the ‘rator’ and t as the ‘rand’ (short for ‘operator’ and ‘operand’ respectively).
Abstractions of an arbitrary lambda-term s over a variable x (which may or may not occur free in s), denoted by λx. s.
Formally, this defines the set of lambda terms inductively, i.e. lambda terms arise only in these four ways.

Given the lambda term: $(\lambda x \cdot v)(\lambda v \cdot x)$
I am unsure if it is a combination or an abstraction since if I inspected each of the parentheses individually I would categorise $(\lambda x \cdot v)$ to be an abstraction and the same for $(\lambda v \cdot x)$. But since they are "combined" do we now call it a combination?
Extra: Are $v$ and $x$ free or bound variables in this case? Again in the same example if we inspected $(\lambda v \cdot x)$ by itself I would say $v$ is bound and $x$ is free. But now since they are combined are both now bound?

Both $x$ and $v$ are free. The term is $\alpha$-equivalent (hence equal) to $(\lambda a. v)(\lambda b. x)$. Note that "combinations" are more often called applications. The term is an application of an abstraction to another abstraction.

(1) it's a combination. You can think of a term as being built up from variables using a sequence of applications and abstractions. The term is called an abstraction when the final operation used was abstraction. It doesn't matter whether or not some sub terms are abstractions.
(2) The first occurrence of v is free and the second occurrence of x is free. The second occurrence of v and the first of x are bound. With the usual definitions, x and v are both free variables in that term. The rule for FV( M N ) (the set of free variables in an application M N) that it is the union of FV(M) and FV(N)
